# How to access a JSON object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

How do i access the JSON object in javascript whena  JSON object is something like this.

`{'':'my-first-Name'}`

The Name of the property is empty and i am not able to access it.

Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always access object's property by index of key. For example:

```
 var object = {'':'my-first-Name'};
 var value = object[''];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can access by this

```js
var v={'':'my-first-Name'};

document.write(v['']);
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var x = {'':'my-first-Name'}
alert(x['']);
```